# How to substitute a pattern with different strings in multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, perl, scripting

I'm in the process of adding java annotations to multiple test files. I have to do this for test methods in multiple files for over 100+ places.

Using some scripting/regular expressions, I have got the annotations in place. Remaining part is providing attribute values for these annotations e.g. as in the case below, I need to replace `value = "search_pattern"` with `value="replace_string1"` where `replace_string1` is the name of function for which the annotation is being added (it appears few lines below the annotation, see the snippet for reference).

Each file can have multiple functions to apply annotations, and there are many such files.

Is there a way to script this?

I haven't found any luck with `sed` yet and I don't want to do all of this manually.

```
@Prop(name = "Operation", value = "search_pattern")
...
@Test
public void replace_string1() {
    ...     
 }

@Prop(name = "Operation", value = "search_pattern")
...
@Test
public void replace_string2() {

}
```

Comment: Your question looks a bit terse at the moment. Kindly consider adding more detail.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'd love to take a go at answering this question, but there isn't enough in the question for me to understand what you're actually looking for.  If you want to do something in bash, please include the bash code you've written so far, explain precisely what you want it to do, give an example of the output you're getting (based on the input you'll include in the question) along with the output you're looking for.

Comment: sjsam@ / ghoti@ , I rephrased question. Hope it is better now

Comment: Okay, this is a little clearer now. How much space exists between the `@Prop` line to be modified and the `public void` line which contains the replacement text?

Comment: In my case, there are 4 more lines. Aside, the solution suggested by thanasisp@ works irrespective of how many lines are in between.

Comment: That solution only works on systems with `tac` installed.

Comment: ghoti@, if ```tac``` is not available, there are alternatives like ```tail -r``` e.g. on Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the help of `tac` which prints the file in reversed order, so we call it again at the end.

```
tac file | awk '/^public void/ {v=$3; sub(/\(\)/,"",v)}
     /^@Prop\(name = \"Operation\"/ {sub(/search_pattern/,v,$0)} 1' |tac
```

[here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) you can see for the `awk` function `sub`. `1` at the end means to print.

So for example if you want to do it for all `*.java` in a directory, you can run something like this:

```
for f in *.java ; do
    tac "$f" | awk '/^public void/ {v=$3; sub(/\(\)/,"",v)}
         /^@Prop\(name = \"Operation\"/ {sub(/search_pattern/,v,$0)}
         1' |tac > temp && mv temp "$f"
done
```

the last `mv` command replaces the file without prompt so you must have tested without it before running.

Comment: thanasisp@, you and ```awk``` are the saviors :) I can't thank you enough. And unfortunately I can not upvote due to lack of reputation.